# Best way to enqueue events received from websocket for asynchronous processing

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have a java application receiving events from Discord's websocket using JDA, my goal is to enqueue these events (I've been using LinkedBlockingQueues, but if there's a better tool for that suggestions are very much welcome) for processing on multiple object instances (Consumers) asynchronously, each with their own queue.

Note that there might and will be queues that need to operate on the same element, thus just sharing the queue between threads would not work.

First thing I tried was to clone the blocking queue using

```
 BlockingQueue<T> original = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();
 BlockingQueue<T> clone = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>(original);
```

but this would only copy the events present on the queue at that time, not actually tie the producer with the clone as well so it does not work.

I've also tried assigning one listener to each of the consumers but this seems way less efficient to do on runtime with jda.

The approach I've been taking is to feed all the events to a main queue and start a thread which would pass all these events into parallel queues distributed through all the instances, but this just seems very inneficient and unclean.

What would be the best, cleanest, most efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just share the queue vs cloning it across multiple threads?

```
 BlockingQueue<T> original = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();

Thread consumer1 = new Thread(new Consumer(original));
Thread consumer2 = new Thread(new Consumer(original));

consumer1.start();
consumer2.start();
```

Or if you can, use a message broker (ie, Rabbit MQ) type of solution where the producer produces to a TOPIC and you can have multiple Consumers that have subscribed to the topic, each with their own work / business process flow. 
This approach would also give you safety should your VM crash as the queue would stored elsewhere.

Comment: If I share the queue like that, when I call `queue.take()` on it, won't the element be removed from every single instance, thus only being processed by a single thread?

Comment: I feel as though this site will provide some good information. https://www.baeldung.com/java-blocking-queue. 
However, if you need multiple workflow to happen after you drain a given queue aka TAKE.. you could have it call multiple methods at the same time. 
EG.
int customerId = blah.take();
incrementWebHits(customerId);
validateInfo(customerId);
closeSession(customerId);

Comment: I see, taking just one time and distributing the actual element instead of the queue for the consumer, this would be much more efficient than iterating and operating on hundreds of entire queues every few cycles, I will try that, thank you very much. What you suggested before was also good but I guess I didn't state that I needed the various consumers to operate on the **same** element properly, I will structure the question better.

Comment: If it weren't after midnight / 1am I probably would have understood your question better. haha. good luck